# How can analytics be reporting page requests from IE9 on Windows 8.1?

Tags: analytics, user-agent, azure-application-insights

How is that the analytics is reporting page requests from IE7 & IE9 from Windows NT 6.3 (Windows 8.1). How is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is that the users' browser is "locked" into IE9 mode; this can be done via F12 dev tools. Sometimes enterprise policy might even have changed the document mode, which can affect what IE reports in its user agent.  I accidentally did this to myself a couple months ago, and I was confused as well!

Comment: This seems logical. Thanks Brett.